# SQL is a linking/bridge table needed?

Tags: sql-server

I currently have two joined tables in a SQL Server database, one with news items (newsTab) and a table (usrCom) which captures multiple user comments for each article.

I want to add another information table (infoTab) which will also allow users to comment but I wish to use the existing comments table (usrCom) to store these.

How do I go about creating a linking/bridge table which generates a unique ID so I know which table (newsTab/infoTab) the comments belong to.

NB: I've edited the message to hopefully make it a bit clearer

First Table (newsTab)

```
NewsId    NewsContent
---------------------
1         blah blah
2         and so on
```

Second Table (infoTab)

```
infoId    InfoContent    
---------------------
1         some info
2         more stuff
```

Comments Table (as is currently)

```
commentId    linksTo   Comment
------------------------------
1            1         user input
2            1         random rant
```

'linksTo' is a foriegn key to the items in the first table, so I cannot just add a type column and I would get conflicts on the foreign key column if a row did not exist in the new table with the same ID. So hence the need for a new generated foreign key based upon the table and Id that was being commented on.

Comment: That is a sticky one - we have a database that does something similar, and we used the `NOCHECK` option when constructing the foreign key. Makes it as useful as a chocolate teapot, but does show that there is a relationship between the tables.

Comment: Forgot to say I'm not bothered about the comments that are already there so can start again but I am constained by having a central comment table

Comment: Looks like the only way forward is to merge the News and Info tables and add a type column to that table. That way you will end up with the unique single ID that you can usefully foreign key to.

Comment: Just had a bizarre thought (in case you can't merge the News and Info tables) about having an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on both tables that gets the biggest ID value in either of the tables and increments that before using that value to insert the data into the relevant table. You would end up with your IDs not being sequential in each table, but you would have a unique ID values across the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just a "type" column to the usrCom

Comment: how would I ensure that I had no duplicate id's in the table, as I would be linking on id's which may be duplicates when stored in the comments table, I need to create a unique foreign key based upon which table and id the comment related to, the "type" would have to be part of the key - that's why I thought I needed a bridge table?

Answer (score 0):

If you auto-generate commentId (set as primary key) then you won't get any duplicates in the usrCom table.  Also, if you want to keep one table for comments for both news and info tables, you should add a new column to distinguish which comments are for which tables (call it type).  Then in your queries, make sure you specify the type to filter your results.

To view all comments for newsTab:

```
      select * from usrCom 
      where type='newsTab'
```

Comment: I would want to pull only the comments that are specific to each row in the newsTab not all comments in one go - so need to link to an id that is based upon the record in either the news or info tables as appropriate

The duplicates would potentially be on the foreign key not the primary key